# VS2019 / Typescript 3.7: How to make Intellisense show function description when function is typed

Tags: typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

In a module.ts file, I have defined:

```
/**
 *  My awesome function description
 */
export let myFunc = () => {
    // do something...
    return;
}
```

and in index.ts, I use the function like this:

```
import { myFunc } from "./module.ts";
myFunc();
```

Hovering over "myFunc" gives me proper Intellisense, including the description given in the function declaration ("My awesome function description"):
[link to screenshot: Intellisense showing function description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5AE0.png)

However, if I declare a type in the module and apply it to the function declaration like:

```
declare global {
    /**  MyFunc Type Def */
    type myFuncType = () => void;
}

/**
 *  My awesome function description
 */
export let myFunc:myFuncType = () => {
    // do something...
    return;
}
```

then now Intellisense does not show the function description anymore in index.ts:
[link to screenshot: Intellisense not showing function description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuXCI.png)

In the defining file, module.ts, Intellisense works in both cases.

How can I type the function and have Intellisense show the description?

Comment: Perry, yes, see my comment to your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript just acknowledged the reported problem as a bug, see

[github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35570#issue-534531954](http://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35570#issue-534531954)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I type the function and have Intellisense show the
>   description?

l think there are something wrong with the function written in the **module.ts** file. You don't specify the function, you're missing `()`. So when you call it as **myFunc ()**, you can't find the specific function so that you're missing the description file.

And you just have to add `()` when you define it.
You can refer to this sample which l have tested successfully.

```
declare global {
    /**  MyFunc Type Def */
    type myFuncType = () => void;
}

/**
 *  My awesome function description
 */
export let myFunc=(): myFuncType =>{
    // do something...
    return;
}
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Perry, thank you for answering. When I follow your example, Intellisense works, but it only works for the simple example I posted. If you add typed parameters to your type & function, the function itself doesnt work anymore.


TypeScript just acknowledged the reported problem as a bug, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35570#issue-534531954